# Oracle 18c count(*) from dba_tables returns zero even after providing select grants

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle18c

We are trying to get the count of tables from dba_tables in a pl/sql procedure and the count returns as zero. We are able to see the count view the records of dba_tables through sql developer. However, through pl/sql code this returns as zero.

Please find the sample code below, We currently have 2 schemas running on the same database. We had provided select grants on dba_tables for both the schema users.

```
declare
l_count number :=0;
begin
select count(1) into l_count from dba_tables where owner ='USER1';
dbms_output.put_line('count for user 1 is ' || l_count);
l_count := 0;
select count(1) into l_count from dba_tables where owner ='USER2';
dbms_output.put_line('count for user 2 is ' || l_count);
end;
```

output that we get is:
count for user 1 is 0
count for user 2 is 0

Output that we get for the same queries from sql developer is:

```
select count(1) from dba_tables where owner ='USER1'; --result is 5892
select count(1) from dba_tables where owner ='USER2'; --result is 6124
```

Thanks in advance, it would be really greatful if someone can help me out with this.

Comment: It comes to the same thing, but the standard SQL expression is `count(*)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grant on dba_tables has to be to the user who owns/is running the procedure.

It works in SQL if the caller has the grant via a role, but in PL/SQL the grant has to be directly to the user name.

Comment: Thank you!!! We granted the select rights directly to the user name and it worked.

Comment: You should accept the answer as it resolved your problem.